# How to edit magento home page via code?

Tags: magento

Hello I'm trying to edit home page

http://www.kreatifyazilim.com/magento/

For example I want to write code on the middle part of the page, ( banner )

The dropdown boxes you can see on demo must be included in banner side.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Magento admin->CMS->Pages

Select Home Page

In Content Tab, add your dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template (`home.phtml`). 
(make a copy of `design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml`).

And choose this template in the CMS Page design layout.

You can freely edit the complete template (PHP+HTML)

Comment: this solution will destroy templating of any other 1column page eg : cart, checkout...

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf I'm not saying to overwrite the 1column.phtml template. I'm saying; create a new template (homepage.phtml) and copy the 1column.phtml contents to have a starting template. This does not affect any other page that utilizes the 1column.phtml